# ASUS Laptop Screen Hertz Issue

Tags: power-supply, power, laptop

I currently have an issue with my ASUS laptop.

When the power is unplugged the screen refresh rate drops down to 48 hertz from 120 hertz

This caused the screen to glich and cut in half so that the screen is only displayed on the top half of my screen. I then have to manually change the refresh rate to 120 again so that I can use my laptop normally.

Does anyone know how I can stop my laptop from automatically dropping to 48 hertz so that this doesnt happen again ?

Edit : I am currently using Windows 10 version : 21H1

Comment: Looks to me like it's caused by power save when running on battery. What OS do you use? Please don't answer in a comment, but update your question instead.

Comment: You may need to check the power settings from your graphics adapter's control panel. I'm sure Intel HD Graphics Control Panel has a similar setting, but I'm not sure about Nvidia's or AMD Radeon's. I don't know what graphics adapter your laptop has, so I can't put a workaround or a full solution here for you.